# Prevent WAMP from loading external requests

Tags: curl, wamp

I need to prevent wamp from loading external links in order to have a better performance

I'm using PrestaShop and sometimes it looks for updates and currency rates etc which slows down loading the page and I get "Waiting for localhost..."

I need a configuration for apache or php that blocks any external request

Comment: Can you turn off the checking for updates in the PrestaShop configuration pages? Currency rate: is this a plugin or built-in to PrestaShop? You could modify your hosts file for the address(es) being connected to redirect to your localhost - they'll not resolve and I have no idea what effect this may have on your site performance...

Comment: I wanted to have a config that blocks any requests without the need to configure PrestaShop or other frameworks and definitely without modifying the hosts file because I might use the same services on my PC

Comment: I blocked Apache outbound connections in my firewall, seems to work pretty well!